# How to start a service on android every time when a SMS message has been send

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm using the following library to read the sms messages that have been sent from my default application. The problem that I'm having is that when the application is close the service is not working to save the message that i have send. Does anyone knows how i can start the service when a message has been sent from my device?

Library
https://github.com/tuenti/SmsRadar

UPDATE 1: 
BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class Broadcast_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT")){
            Intent service = new Intent(context, SMSService.class);
            context.startService(service);
            Log.d("Broadcast_Receiver", "message sent");
        }
        else if ((intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")))
        {
            Log.d("Broadcast_Receiver", "message received");
        }

    }
}
```

manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".APPServices.SMS.Broadcast_Receiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Thank you

Comment: My answer here might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083158/send-sms-until-it-is-successful/19084559#19084559

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a "Broadcast Reciever" for that

As the name suggests:  broadcast receiver waits for an event to occur and when the event occurs , it receives that info, which was broadcast-ed by the event.

Here is a great tutorial which describes how to implement it step by step (A little long to type it here)

http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87

Comment: this is for incoming messages. i'm interesting only on outgoing messages

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910308/how-to-track-the-messages-in-android/10910674#10910674

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990558/android-broadcast-receiver-for-sent-sms-messages

Comment: i tried the second post that you gave me but the BroadcastReceiver is not been called on the onReceive. I have registered the BroadcastReceiver inside the manifest

Comment: Post a question with your code and what you've tried so far , and be as specific as possible.  I'll try my best to answer and it will also get attention of others